# Get hierarchical categories of a parent category

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I need a query who select me all child categorys with a given parent id. My table looks like the following:

```
|ID | Title | Description | ParentId
--------------------------------------
 1  | Games | ...         | NULL
```

and so on..

Is it possible to solve this with a sql-query?

Give me all child categories of the category games..

All child categories could have more child categories and so on..

I need this for my website menu to list products..
**My Attempt**
Use CocoDb 
Go

```
;WITH parent 
  AS ( SELECT ParentId 
       FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] 
       WHERE Id = 11 ) 
,tree AS ( SELECT x.ParentId, x.Id 
           FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] x 
                 INNER JOIN [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] ON x.Id = 11
            UNION ALL 
           SELECT y.Id, y.ParentId FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] y 
             INNER JOIN [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] t ON y.Id = t.ParentId )
```

Solution:

```
;WITH parent 
  AS ( SELECT ParentId, Title, Id 
       FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] 
       WHERE Id = 1
      ) 
,tree AS ( 
           SELECT x.ParentId, x.Id, x.Title 
           FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] x 
                 INNER JOIN parent ON x.ParentId = parent.Id
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT y.ParentId, y.Id, y.Title 
           FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] y 
            INNER JOIN tree t ON y.ParentId = t.Id 
          )
SELECT *
FROM Tree
```

Comment: Look into recursion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH parent AS 
    (
    SELECT Parent
    FROM Table1
    WHERE Child = @p0
    )    
,tree AS 
    (
    SELECT x.Parent, x.Child
    FROM Table1 x
    INNER JOIN parent ON x.Parent = parent.Parent
    UNION ALL
    SELECT y.Parent, y.Child
    FROM Table1 y
    INNER JOIN tree t ON y.Parent = t.Child
    )
      SELECT Parent, Child
      FROM tree
```

**Update For your Query**

```
;WITH parent 
  AS ( SELECT ParentId 
       FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] 
       WHERE Id = 11 
      ) 
,tree AS ( 
           SELECT x.ParentId, x.Id 
           FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] x 
                 INNER JOIN parent ON x.ParentId = parent.ParentId
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT y.ParentId, y.Id 
           FROM [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] y 
            INNER JOIN tree t ON y.ParentId = t.Id 
          )
SELECT parent, Child 
FROM Tree
```

Make sure you use `;` before `WITH` like I have used in above queries.

Comment: @Patrik test here it works for this data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3cb21/1 , Assuming you are looking for childer tree for Parent where ID = 2

Comment: Update your question so everyone can read it really hard to read a question in comments section.

Comment: parent.Parent is unknown.. :-/ INNER JOIN [CocoDb].[dbo].[Categories] ON x.Id = parent.ParentId

Comment: its not the actual (Hardcoded) parent.id but Parent ID from 1st Cte which i Called "Parent", I have two CTEs in this solution One with the name of "Parent" and Other one "Tree", just execute the query I have put in Update answer should return all the child records for any parent ID passed in the very 1st Parent CTE.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C.*
FROM <TABLE> C INNER JOIN <TABLE> P
ON P.ID=C.PARENTID
WHERE PARENTID=<GIVEN PARENTID>
```